# How to create a string from many strings efficiently in Java

Tags: java, string

In a Java code, I have 11 different strings, some of them (at most 9) can be null. Strings are a part of an object. If none of them is null, I make a string like this :

```
string1 + "," + string2 + "," + string3 + "," + string4 + "," + string5 + "," + string6 + "(" + string7 + ")" + string8 + string9 + "+" + string10 + string11
```

If none of them is null, it's okey. But some of them can be null. If I check if each of them is null, code gets really slow and long. How can I generate such a string in an efficient and fast way? Thanks.

Comment: Can you use an array?

Comment: What result do you want to get when the strings are null? As it stands, you'll just get the string `null` in your result - there won't be an error or anything like that.

Comment: @Arc676 Could you show with a simple example? Thanks.

Comment: You can declare a helper method `String emptyForNull(String s) { return s == null ? "" : s; }`

Comment: @RealSkeptic I want to get such a result that, that string never exists. For example if string2 is null, I need to get `string1 + "," + string3...`

Comment: The above comment can help with that. Also, jason, I need to know how you get your strings first. You should add that to your question

Comment: not sure what you mean by long as slow, well if you want to make you code shorter, rather than having string1,string2 and etc, you can have an array string[] strings instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string1 = "test1";
    String string2 = "test2";
    String string3 = "test3";
    String string4 = null;
    String string5 = "test5";

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<>();
    valueList.add(string1);
    valueList.add(string2);
    valueList.add(string3);
    valueList.add(string4);
    valueList.add(string5);
    // etc.

    for (String value : valueList) {
        if (value != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(value);
        }
        else {
            value = ",";
            stringBuilder.append(value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(stringBuilder);
}
```

Output :

> test1test2test3,test5

Comment: The problem is that there are parts in the output string that are supposed to be in parentheses, parts that are not separated by comma, parts that are separated by `+`...

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 you could use this for the first part with comma-delimited strings:

```
String part1 = Stream.of(string1, string2, string3, string4, string5, string6)
                     .filter(Objects.notNull())
                     .collect(joining(",");
```

From then on you have an irregular structure so you'll need custom logic to handle it. The helper function

```
static String emptyForNull(String s) {
  return s == null ? "" : s;
}
```

can get you part of the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want your code to be as short as possible, use String.format and get rid of the "null" in the string.

```
String result = String.format("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s(%s)%s,%s,%s,%s",
            string1, string2, string3, string4, string5,
            string6, string7, string8, string9, string10,
            string11);

    System.out.println(result.replace("null", ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, you can stream and join with Collectors, and filter with Objects classes

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("first", "second", null, "third", null, null, "fourth");
String res = strings.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
System.out.println(res);
```

results in output

```
first,second,third,fourth
```

Answer (score 1):

If 6th index of your string is always surrounded by `(` and `)` then you can use following code.

```
    List<String> vals = new ArrayList<>();
    vals.add(string1);
    vals.add(string2);
    vals.add(string3);
    vals.add(string4);
    vals.add(string5);
    vals.add(string6);
    vals.add(string7);
    vals.add(string8);
    vals.add(string9);
    vals.add(string10);
    vals.add(string11);

    for (int i =0 ; i < vals.size(); i++) {
        // check null values
        if (vals.get(i) != null) {
        // as your requirement surround 7th value with ( and )
            if(vals.indexOf(vals.get(i)) == 6) {
                values += "\b(" + vals.get(i)+")";
            } else {
                values += vals.get(i)+",";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(values+"\b");
```

**Output**
if 4th and 9th strings are `null` then,

`test1,test2,test3,test5,test6(test7)test8,test10,test11`